# Overfitting LSTM pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I was following the tutorial on [CoderzColumn](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/artificial-intelligence/pytorch-lstm-for-text-classification-tasks) to implement a LSTM for text classification using pytorch. I tried to apply the implementation on the [bbc-news Dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/balatmak/newsgroup20bbcnews/), however, it heavily overfits, achieving a max accuracy of about 60%.

See the train/loss curve for example:

[image]

Is there any advice (I am quite new to RNN/LSTM), to adapt the model to prevent that high overfiting?

The model is taken from the above tutorial and looks kind of like this:

```py
class LSTMClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab, target_classes, embed_len = 50, hidden_dim=75, n_layers=1):
        super(LSTMClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.embed_len = embed_len
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.embedding_layer = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=len(vocab), embedding_dim=embed_len)
      #  self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embed_len, hidden_size=hidden_dim,dropout=0.2, num_layers=n_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embed_len, hidden_size=hidden_dim, num_layers=n_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, len(target_classes))

    def forward(self, X_batch):
        embeddings = self.embedding_layer(X_batch)
        hidden, carry = torch.randn(self.n_layers, len(X_batch), self.hidden_dim), torch.randn(self.n_layers, len(X_batch), self.hidden_dim)
        output, (hidden, carry) = self.lstm(embeddings, (hidden, carry))

        return self.fc(output[:,-1])
```

I would be really thankful for any adive how to adapt the version in the tutorial to use it more effectively on other datasets

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding `nn.Dropout` layer before the `self.fc`?
Check what `p = 0.1 / 0.2 / 0.3` will do.

Another thing you can do is to add regularisation to your training via `weight_decay` parameter:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4, weight_decay=1e-5)
```

Use small values first, and increase by 10 times, see which will get you the best result.

Also, goes without saying, make sure that there is no test data points in  train set. Make sure you did not forget to shuffle your train set:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=1024, collate_fn=vectorize_batch, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. That helped a little bit, however I am still not reaching good performance and still oveftis a lot.

Comment: Try increasing number of word per news article. If you are following the tutorial you've mentioned to the letter, it only uses 25 words per article. It is way too small, try using like 1000 or so.